# How to add a static item, eg "Add new contact", always as the first item of the recycler view?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview

I am trying to design a RecyclerView along with Firestore, which will display the list of customers, but I want to have a "add new customer" option as the first item of the recycler view, something similar to WhatsApp contact.

I can design a different view for the "add new customer" but have no idea how to display it as the first item in the recycler view. Adding a picture for reference.

Please suggest how to achieve this.

Thanks
Suman[image]

Comment: add static data for this in your list and after that append the real data from firestore.

Comment: I think multiple fragment for one activity  will do the work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not add that "add new customer" option as an element of the `RecyclerView`. That should simply be a `TextView` added before the `RecyclerView` in vertical `LinearLayout`. Attach a click listener, and add the desired logic to it.

Or add the exact `TextView` as the first position in the adapter that renders your `RecyclerView`.